# Is it unprofessional or rude to say that someone is being frustrated?

Tags: work-environment, colleagues, work-experience

**Summary**: Contractor got upset and frustrated that we have chosen the other agency based on given quotes. I've tried to diffuse the situation by saying "I don't understand why you are frustrated", but the contractor got even more upset, calling that comment unprofessional. Is it unprofessional or rude to tell someone that they are frustrated?

---

We had group discussion with our contractors as well about a work task. First company (A) said this is not within their scope of work but they could do it and gave us a quote. The other external agency (B) said they could do it and provided us with quote we didn't asked for and it was more that the other company quote. But having this information we decided based on price comparison.

The other external agency (B) manager started passive-aggressive conversation that we are delaying the project by asking them to quote us. Although we haven't asked him for it. Overall he got probably upset that we didn't tell him we will decide based on cost. During the conversation I said that there is not need to be frustrated about this. As overall we are working as team and we should be able to support each other if needed. He then got very angry calling me unprofessional and saying how could I be so rude to call him frustrated, that I personally attacked him.

I don't think I did. Is it really unprofessional to call someone frustrated during work discussion? The only reason why I said that was to make them focus on the work. Their apparent frustration hinder them from having a productive work related discussion.

Comment: I would suggest: You should not, at all, have gotten involved or said anything to them - if they are being idiots ignore them.  You should not have "replied to their nonsense" at all.

Comment: I admit something I do act without thinking about it. I only said: "I don't understand why are you frustrated about this." At the moment I thought he didn't want to share their cost in front of the other agency but seems this wasn't the case. He didn't like the fact we didn't share with him that we would make decision based on cost but on the other hand if you have two external agencies working together on one project, both sharing their cost who would you give the work to. Probably the cheaper one.

Comment: i've added Summary, feel free to edit it to reflect your question better

Comment: Thank you. I had to edit it a bit as it didn't show what happened exactly.

Comment: You mentioned that both companies provided you a quote, but you only complained about company B giving you a quote ("we didn't ask for"), why was the quoting company B gave you not something you asked for?  Clearly, the additional work was out of the scope of the current contract.  As for the contractor not realizing you would decide on price, that is typically how decisions are made, you don't have to specifically indicate the price is one of the factors you will use to decide on which contractor to use (it's obvious as the sky is blue).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**It can come off as dismissive.**

This really depends on the culture, but depending on the presentation, tone, and other elements, it can be interpreted as "you are being irrationally angry."

> I said that there is not need to be frustrated about this. As overall we are working as team and we should be able to support each other if needed.

You also insinuated that he was not a team player.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it unprofessional or rude to say that someone is being frustrated?

Yes it is.  Accusing someone of being frustrated is a personal attack and has no business in a professional environment.  When you are discussing work related issues, stick to discussing the work related issues whether or not you believe that one of the participants is frustrated.

If you think that their apparent frustrations would hinder them from having a productive work related discussion you can say something like:

> Let's table this discussion for now so that I can gather some additional information and I will set up a meeting to discuss.

Take this time to gather your thoughts and prepare a cohesive non-personal argument to support your position.  When you two meet again, make sure that you do not make any personal comments about the other person(s).

Answer (score 2):

As pointed in other answers, saying "there is no need to be frustrated about this" is somewhat unprofessional.

For the future, try to use "[i language](https://www.wikihow.com/Use-%22I%22-Language)". That is, focus on yourself or your company, instead of talking about other people, especially when it comes to other people's feelings.

In your case the conversation should have ended not with "no need to be frustrated" but with some comment about your company, like "we (I) are not ready to make the decision right now", or "We will let you know as soon as we make the decision".

You can also sometimes use "[designated A-hole](https://dev.to/kathryngrayson/the-designated-asshole-lessons-from-my-dad-on-leadership-)" method, and say that "I will have to talk to my boss about making this decision" and end the conversation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is, but assuming this conversation was in English, there is an easy way to deescalate the situation.

Here is what I would say:

> My apologies for yesterday. I'm not a native English speaker. I did not mean to cause offense. I will be more careful with my word choice in the future.

I would email this, to make sure there is a written record of it, and then, I would also follow it up with a quick phone call.

That's it. And yes, saying "that someone is being frustrated" is not something that a native English speaker would say.

In my own native language, which is French, saying something like that would be grammatically correct (but even in French, I would avoid saying something like that unless the person was a dear personal friend of mine, or unless our relationship was really informal).

As a rule of thumb, commenting on and trying to control other people's emotions can be very tricky. For instance, the quickest way to get someone to blow up at you is to tell them to: "Relax."

Now, don't get me wrong. Telling someone to "Relax" may be totally appropriate when you're teaching someone how to swim, or when the person you're speaking to is having a panic attack, or when you're a nurse who's about to stick a person with a syringe, but in most other contexts, it can unnecessarily inflame the person you're speaking to.

Emotions can not easily be turned off. And implying that someone should change their emotional state on your say-so (or implying that they're working themselves up for nothing, even if true) can be considered a personal attack and a way to box them into a corner.

With that said, if a non-native English speaker did say that to me, I would most likely give them the benefit of the doubt. And while I certainly can't be sure if native English speakers would react the same way I would, I wouldn't be surprised if Myles's [hunch](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/172942/14577) was also correct. But I can't be sure of that, because I don't know the tone of voice you used when you made that remark.

Comment: "That's it. And yes, saying "that someone is being frustrated" is not something that a native English speaker would say." I'm a native English speaker, and I think it's fine. I'm not sure why it would unprofessional either, if a person was getting obviously frustrated and upset over something (which would be pretty unprofessional on their behalf).

Comment: @nick012000, No, you'd say "you're being a d___", or "you're frustrating", or "you're frustrated", you wouldn't say "you're being frustrated" (unless you were the coach to a method actor). That just doesn't sound right for the given context. My point is that this can be used as an excuse to de-escalate (not that a huge mistake was made). At least, that's the excuse I like to use when I say annoying things.

Answer (score 0):

As a counterpoint to the other two examples, there is a personality type that will use passive-aggression and faux outrage to create a power imbalance.  Basically they will find something to take offence to to put you in a position to apologize and then take advantage of the fact that you owe them.  I've seen this play out a few times throughout my career, most often the receiver of this behavior is either young or a woman.

I suggest getting the exchange in writing.  That you understand that they are upset that you characterized their reaction as frustrated when they brought up the delay that the quote created and that you invite them to clarify their intention in bringing that up.  Also that you would like to get to the bottom of that delay and if they can please provide record of when and how that quote was requested so that delays of this nature can be avoided in the future.  This puts them on the spot of having to explain why they reacted in a frustrated way if they are not frustrated and why they created a delay providing a quote you never asked for.

My approach to passive-aggression in a work environment is "Please explain your complaint clearly and in writing" and usually the answer is "it's not a problem" without many repeat complaints.  It's really important to come across as 100% polite but formal in these exchanges even if your instincts tell you to soften the message.

Comment: 'Please explain your complaint clearly and in writing' and trying to come across as '100% polite and formal' sounds passive-aggressive to me.